# Symfony2 Doctrine schema update fails

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys

I created database on my local machine. After moving my project to server I imported backup from local (because I had some important data there).

Now,when I'm trying to update schema on my server it gives my this output:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
Updating database schema...





  [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ForeignKeyConstraintViolationException]                                                                                                             
  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE golf_course ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EC96E162F1503E2B FOREIGN KEY (golf_id) REFERENCES golf (id)':                               
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`GolfFairway`.`#sql-3fae_7ccf1`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EC9  
  6E162F1503E2B` FOREIGN KEY (`golf_id`) REFERENCES `golf` (`id`))                                                                                                             






  [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                                                                                                                          
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`GolfFairway`.`#sql-3fae_7ccf1`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EC9  
  6E162F1503E2B` FOREIGN KEY (`golf_id`) REFERENCES `golf` (`id`))                                                                                                             






  [PDOException]                                                                                                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`GolfFairway`.`#sql-3fae_7ccf1`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EC9  
  6E162F1503E2B` FOREIGN KEY (`golf_id`) REFERENCES `golf` (`id`))
```

Why this happens ? Is there a solution ?

Comment: A quick fix as long as you're on you dev environment is : `php app/console doctrine:database:drop` then `php app/console doctrine:schema:create` and finally `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

Comment: actually this is a solution, but I don't want to lose information from Database..

Comment: What does `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` return?

Comment: It returns a list of SQL statemnts. Tried to this manually :

SQL query:

ALTER TABLE golf_course ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EC96E162F1503E2B FOREIGN KEY ( golf_id ) REFERENCES golf( id ) ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`GolfFairway`.`#sql-3fae_7d304`, CONSTRAINT `FK_EC96E162F1503E2B` FOREIGN KEY (`golf_id`) REFERENCES `golf` (`id`))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that you want to modify a table with existing constraint. I see two solutions:

If you are in dev, you can rebuild your database

```
doctrine:database:drop --force
doctrine:database:create
doctrine:schema:create
```

If you're in production it's a little more complicated.

One solution I see is that you could create a command to save your data, delete the data in the tables you want to alter, modify your schema, reload the data once your table is altered. Depending on the changes, it shouldn't take more then 2-3 hours. Just make sure you have a backup in case your command goes south.

Answer (score 30):

@maxian

Michael Villeneuve answer is not totally right. In case of a production environnement or kind of , you just can t drop schema and recreate it.

The only way to perform it on your current schema is by the followings :

1. **php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql . Copy the ouptut. Its the direct SQL queries to update your schema**
2. **connect mysql with mysql command line or through a mysql client**
3. **Disable foreign keys checking by call this query : "set foreign_key_checks=0;"**
4. **put the queries from doctrine:schema:update**
5. **Enable back foreign key checking with : 
   "set foreign_key_checks=1;"**

i cannot guarantee you won t lost some keys but you don t drop your datas at all .

Comment: Great ! Better for syncrhonization without lossing data.

Comment: Saved alot of my hairs :P. This is best solution I have found for production environment so far

Answer (score 10):

### Schema update with foreign-key checks disabled

If Doctrine schema updates fail because of foreign-key constraints, you simply need to disable foreign-key checks for this particular update.

As a one-liner you can run:

```
mysql -e "set foreign_key_checks = 0; `app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`"
```

This prepends `set foreign_key_checks = 0;` to the output of `app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` so it actually calls exactly what Doctrine would call but with foreign-key checks disabled. Configure the `mysql` call to your needs.

Your schema is updated and depending on your changes no data is lost.

Keep in mind that **sometimes the order of the queries is important** and Doctrine simply didn't order them right. In this case you have to order the queries correctly by your own and then use that ordered list of queries instead.

Comment: The best solution for me!

Comment: Trying to  run this, but it doesn't like something about the format:

mysql -uroot -p -e "set foreign_key_checks=0; `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`"

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`' at line 1

Comment: There's a problem with your quotation: You have to use "\`" so that the results of `app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` are piped into the query.

Comment: The first 3 lines of output do not contain SQL, so I added `| tail -n+4` to be able to make this trick work: ``mysql -e "set foreign_key_checks = 0; `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql | tail -n+4`"``

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a value related to the field in the new table.

For example: if you have table A and B,  and B is have the key of A (a_id)  then you need to add a field in A  with id = 1 and in the table B the a_id need to be changed to a value from A table - 1 in this case (make this for all the fields).

After that run :
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Regards

Answer (score -1):

For me it worked with the following setup (with two relations). The trick was to not mix up `mappedBy` and `inversedBy`.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var Merchant
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Merchant", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $merchant;

    /**
     * @var Client
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Client", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $client;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="merchant")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Merchant extends BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="merchant")
     */
    protected $user;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="client")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Client extends BaseEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="client")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```